# Why is this kind configuration file broken and where do I get kind versions

Tags: kubernetes, kind

I am trying to follow this tutorial to learn to use [kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/). The version I just installed using brew install is:
kind version 0.11.1

The config file looks like this:

```yaml
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.sigs.k8s.io/v1alpha3
nodes:
- role: control-plane
  extraPortMappings:
  - containerPort: 30080
    hostPort: 80
    listenAddress: "0.0.0.0"
    protocol: TCP
```

Apparently that version is wrong because I get an error `ERROR: failed to create cluster: unknown apiVersion: kind.sigs.k8s.io/v1alpha3` when I try to create the cluster: `$ kind create cluster --name mycluster --config config/kind.config.yaml --wait 5m`.

I found an example of some other version string, but when trying to add the `spec` block in that same tutorial I get a configuration error. I assume this means because the API broke between the version and the yaml I am using.

Why do I get the original "failed to create cluster" error, and where can I find documentation associating kind versions with yaml syntax?

Comment: Can you provide your `kind` version ? You can check it with the `kind version` command.

Comment: kind version 0.11.1

Answer (score 7):

The version needs to be set to `apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4`

Notice the change from `kind.sigs.k8s.io` to `kind.x-k8s.io` in addition to changing to `v1alpha4`.

Comment: Is there a way to know what's the latest version I should use? Is v1alpha4 still the latest one?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using either a too old or too new `kind` CLI version and that is causing the problem you are witnessing.

I suggest upgrading to the latest `kind` CLI version to ensure your `kind` CLI binary is using the latest `Config` YAML `apiVersion` (`v1alpha4` at the time of writing).

The configuration system is described [here](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/configuration/) and the specifics of the `Cluster` type are described in the [go struct documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/sigs.k8s.io/kind/pkg/apis/config/v1alpha4#Cluster).

Comment: From the docs: "This config merely specifies that we are configuration a KIND cluster (kind: Cluster) and that the version of KIND's config we are using is v1alpha4 (apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4)"

Ok,  but that doesn't tell me what these strings mean? How do I know what version supports what syntax?

Comment: Did you check the other link? The go doc page?

Comment: is there no longer a Deployment kind in version v1alpha4? I am trying to follow this example https://www.appvia.io/blog/tutorial-deploy-kubernetes-cluster and the deploy manifest shows kind as Deployment which I don't see documented in the go docs.

Comment: I get error - no matches for kind "Cluster" in version "kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4".  Yes its in the go doc, but that's just documentation.  There is something amiss here, I suspect some configuration that needs doing, that isn't documented..